# Dockerのコンテナが立ち上がらない

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Docker使い始めの者です。
docker create --name wow centos
を用いてwowという名前のコンテナを作りそこに接続（？）しようとしたところ、execもattachもできずに困っています。

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
centos              latest              0f3e07c0138f        33 hours ago        220MB
nginx               latest              f949e7d76d63        8 days ago          126MB

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
4c8c97fd5dc1        centos              "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       wow

$ docker start wow
wow

$ docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker exec -it wow /bin/bash
Error response from daemon: Container 4c8c97fd5dc1f98033d71063de8dfb27755f779433af39f00b9ded1c9a7d655a is not running

$ docker attach wow
You cannot attach to a stopped container, start it first
```

コマンドが違うのでしょうか、そもそもstartでちゃんとコンテナが立ち上がっていないようなのです。

環境は
OS：macOS Mojave 10.14.6
Docker: 2.1.0.3

Comment: `docker ps -a --no-trunc`とうつとどうなりますか？

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます`$ docker ps -a --no-trunc
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
4c8c97fd5dc1f98033d71063de8dfb27755f779433af39f00b9ded1c9a7d655a   centos              "/bin/bash"         29 hours ago        Exited (0) 25 hours ago         `となりました。すみません書式が整いません。

Comment: コメント欄では改行がシンタックスハイライトが使えませんので、アドバイスを受けた結果も直接本文に対して追記をすればOKだと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

根本的な解決には繋がりませんでしたが、こうなってしまうのを避ける道はありました。
`docker run`
を用いれば起動状態でコンテナ作成されますので
そうすれば一度抜けた後も特に問題なく入ることができました。

……よくわかりません。

Answer (score 0):

システムコールのトレースを取ると原因がわかるかもしれません。
※あるはずの設定ファイルがなくてopenに失敗しているなど
Linux系では`strace`、solarisでは`truss`を使います。

MacOSでトレースを取ったことはありませんが、次のページを見つけました。
[MacOSXでstraceが欲しいけどdtrace意味わからん→dtruss使おう](https://qiita.com/hnw/items/269f8eb44614556bd6bf)
[macOS でシステムコールトレースを取得する](https://yohei-a.hatenablog.jp/entry/20171206/1512579504)

これらの記事によれば`dtruss`でコマンドを起動すると`strace`相当のことができるようです。

```
sudo dtruss -f sudo -u $(id -u -n)  docker attach wow
```

実行前に`man dtrace`で使い方を調べた方がいいです。
大量のトレースログが出るので注意してください。